# Start service autamatically on startup at Ubuntu

Tags: startup, services

I accidentally screw up my NetworkManager.service when I was playing around 
with some network configurations. When I open my Linux I need to run

```
systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

In order to have Internet. How can I configure this service to run again on starup automatically. I have Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `enable`

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```